# Is it possible to assign worker resources to dask distributed worker after creation?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

As per title, if I am creating workers via helm or kubernetes, is it possible to assign "worker resources" (https://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resources.html#worker-resources) after workers have been created?

The use case is tasks that hit a database, I would like to limit the amount of processes able to hit the database in a given run, without limiting the total size of the cluster.

Comment: Okay another dig through the code, I found `set_resources`. I assume I could do a `client.run(lambda x: set_resources('my-db')`.

Would this be the most appropriate way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 2019-04-09 there is no standard way to do this.  You've found the `Worker.set_resources` method, which is reasonable to use.  Eventually I would also expect Worker plugins to handle this, but they aren't implemented.

For your application of controlling access to a database, it sounds like what you're really after is a semaphore.  You might [help build one](https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/2007) (it's actually decently straightforward given the current `Lock` implementation), or you could use a [Dask Queue](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/futures.html#distributed.Queue) to simulate one.